# PHP mysqli connection to remote database

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to connect to a database that is not on the same host as my site for the first time and not having much luck. The DB is on a godaddy host and I have configured it to allow remote access:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);

if (!$dbc) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

and I get the following on page:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: [2002] Connection
>   timed out (trying to connect via ‘mydbhostname:3306) in ‘path’ on line
>   3
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2002):
>   Connection timed out in ‘path’ on line 3
>
> Connect Error: Connection timed out

Anything I need to look for on my end or something in the script that could be causing this?

EDIT: well it appears everything works when I use mysql, but not mysqli...and mysqli is enabled on the server.

Comment: Use localhost instead if it is on the same server? Is it using a different port perhaps?

Comment: Thats the whole issue, it is not on the same server.

Comment: Are you sure "mydbhostname" is the uri for your database?

Comment: that was just me putting in a dumby host name here. I have confirmed with the company that I have the proper hostname.

Comment: Blunt question but how long ago did you setup your sql database some hosts have a qeue about 2-5min delay for activation. Time out is result of dropped connection so either the db has not been activated yet or your host is blocking your port or there could be another application using said port.

Comment: It has been setup for over five hours now.

Comment: I am having the same problem and it is 2014 now. The mysql example works but mysqli does not. I checked with phpinfo.php and it says that mysqli is enabled on godaddy. The PHP version here is 5.3.24. Staying with mysql is not really an option as it is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.

Comment: Did you try PDO instead mysqli?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Digitalocean Ubuntu 14.04 server, where the firewall configuration  was the culprit. Mysql wasn't allowed on port 3306 by the ufw firewall rules.

Solution:

```
$ sudo ufw status
$ sudo ufw allow mysql
$ sudo ufw reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have inserted correct hostname for your database, here you can see how to do it on godaddy hosting:

- http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4978/connecting-remotely-to-shared-hosting-databases
- http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/39/locating-your-databases-host-name?locale=en

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand the difference between mysqli and mysql, but I've found on GoDaddy that using:

mysqli_connect doesn't work. 
mysql_connect does work.

Try using the following sample code to see if you can connect to your database which needs data in at least one table:

```
<?php
//Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.
$hostname = "XXXXXXX.db.XXXXXXXX.hostedresource.com";
$username = "XXXXXXX";
$dbname = "XXXXXXX";

//These variable values need to be changed by you before deploying
$password = "XXXXXXX";
$usertable = "XXXXXXX";
$yourfield = "XXXXXXX";

//Connecting to your database
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to
connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//Fetching from your database table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row["$yourfield"];
        echo "<h2>some data</h2>";
        echo "$name<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Godaddy doesn't support mysqli? That seems very unlikely to me. However I completely disagree with recommending the usage of the deprecated ext/mysql. If anything, recommend PDO, but not ext/mysql.

Comment: I've run into this same problem in 2016. Using phpInfo(); in a test script shows that GoDaddy has mysqli installed. Making a connection to the database works OK, but trying to fetch records doesn't work using mysqli. Their PHP version is 5.4.45. According to this PHP page, mysql_connect is deprecated in version 5.5. If they upgrade PHP versions, it will break websites. I recommend creating both the mysql_connect & a mysqli_connect block. Then checking the server's PHP version. Use mysqli when PHP > 5.5+ else use mysql when PHP < 5.4x. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php